I don't know why I cannot got sessionID when I used expo to catch clerk sessionID
I don't know why I cannot got sessionID when I used expo to catch clerk sessionID.
Also, I still cannot see the any errors.
  useWarmUpBrowser();

  const router = useRouter();
  const { startOAuthFlow: googleAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_google' });
  const { startOAuthFlow: appleAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_apple' });
  const { startOAuthFlow: facebookAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_facebook' });

  const onSelectAuth = async (strategy: Strategy) => {
    const selectedAuth = {
      [Strategy.Google]: googleAuth,
      [Strategy.Apple]: appleAuth,
      [Strategy.Facebook]: facebookAuth,
    }[strategy];

    try {
      const { createdSessionId, setActive } = await selectedAuth();
      

      if (createdSessionId) {
        setActive!({ session: createdSessionId });
        console.log("onSelectAuth~~~ createdSessionID", createdSessionId)
        router.back();
      } else {
        console.log("ERRRRRRRRRRROR")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('OAuth error', err);
    }
  };

I tried to used apple, google, Facebook to sign up. it's same problems.
Did I missing something to set up?
Console.log show
 LOG  ERRRRRRRRRRROR 

it's not get sessionID
button code
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnOutline} onPress={() => onSelectAuth(Strategy.Apple)}>
          <Ionicons name="logo-apple" size={24} style={defaultStyles.btnIcon} />
          <Text style={styles.btnOutlineText}>Continue with Apple</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


I faced similar issues. This is being caused because in the 'Clerk' dashboard, the email and phone-number fields are enabled by default. Your signin method may not have those fields.

The above settings are enabled by default in clerk when you create an application. Change it to the below shown settings.

